# How to unit test error scenarios for creating DOM element with angular

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I created a service to add `canonical` tag.

Below is the service code,

```
  createLinkForCanonicalURL(tagData) {
    try {
      if (!tagData) {
        return;
      }
      const link: HTMLLinkElement = this.dom.createElement('link');

      Object.keys(tagData).forEach((prop: string) => {
        link.setAttribute(prop, tagData[prop]);
      });

      this.dom.head.appendChild(link);
    } catch (e) {}
  }
```

I could successfully unit this function with the below spec.

```
  it('should create link tag', () => {
    seoLinkService.createLinkForCanonicalURL({rel: 'canonical', href: 'www.example.org'});
    expect(document.querySelector("link").getAttribute('rel')).toEqual('canonical');
    expect(document.querySelector("link").getAttribute('href')).toEqual('www.example.org');
  });
```

But I'm trying to test the error scenarios.

Below is the spec,

```
  it('should not create link tag', () => {
    seoLinkService.createLinkForCanonicalURL(undefined);
    expect(document.querySelector("link").getAttribute('rel')).toBeFalsy();
  });
```

With the above code my spec's failed with the below message.

> Expected 'canonical' to be falsy.

How do I test error scenario. Please help.

Comment: How did you declare the `dom`?

Comment: in constructor `@Inject(DOCUMENT) private dom`

Comment: Because the `link` you created before still exists in the document.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the before created link tag in the `beforeEach`.

Like this:

```
describe('test', () => {

  ...

  beforeEach(() => {
    document.querySelectorAll("link").forEach(e => e.remove());
  })


  it('should create link tag', () => {
    seoLinkService.createLinkForCanonicalURL({rel: 'canonical', href: 'www.example.org'});
    expect(document.querySelector("link").getAttribute('rel')).toEqual('canonical');
    expect(document.querySelector("link").getAttribute('href')).toEqual('www.example.org');
  });

  it('should not create link tag', () => {
    seoLinkService.createLinkForCanonicalURL(undefined);
    expect(document.querySelector("link").getAttribute('rel')).toBeFalsy();
  });
})
```

Comment: Also, if I re-arrage the test case it works. I've been breaking my head with it